# Nissan qashqai heater problems

Tags: heater

Not blowing  hot air out of heater vent , motor  working  on all settings  both matrix pipes are warm when car is at operating temperature

Comment: The matrix pipes are only warm?  Are they rubber pipes?  If they are metal, I would expect them to be too hot to hold.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely issue is with what is called the "blend door" actuator.  The blend door is a movable door that mixes the air from 100% cold to 100% hot as you adjust the temperature control.  In some cars this is just a cable but today it's usually an electrical or vacuum operated motor.  These are tiny things and they wear out and break over time.

It's not clear what year your Nissan is but this page:

[HVAC Parts Diagram](https://www.carid.com/nissan-oe/hvac-blend-door-actuator-mpn-277305rb0a.html?view=058041&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIt7yY3f6d9QIV9vLjBx1DMwOQEAQYBSABEgKnd_D_BwE)

Shows the part for some years:

[image: Blend Door Actuator]